# XPath evaluate for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath, internet-explorer-9

Hi everyone I need to use XPath functions for all browsers, my code so far works on every other browser except for IE, who doesn't support these functions. Any idea how to proceed? Any library i can use that is compatible with all the browsers?
Thanks

Comment: When you say your code works, what do you mean? What are you doing with it? How are you using it?

Comment: Im getting data from xml file, depending on the xpath im using i get different attributes and nodes.

Comment: What do you want to do?